Find the Inverse Laplace Transform of Θ(s)
I am asked to find the inverse Laplace transform of the following: $$Θ(s)=\frac{2^{n+1}n!}{s^{n+1}}$$
It is my understanding that the following are true: $$L^{-1}(F(ks))(t)=\frac{1}{k}f(t/k)$$ $$L^{-1}(F(as+b))(t)=\frac{1}{a}e^{-bt/a}f(t/a)$$
We have these when $F(s)=L(f)(s)$ exists for $s>a≥0$ and for any constants $a$, $b$, and $k$ with $a$ and $k$ are positive.
I don't need have trouble showing how this is true, but I'm wondering what to do next regarding $Θ(s)$.
Am I supposed to express it as a scaled version of the basic function: $$\frac{1}{s^{n+1}}$$ If this true then I think I can use the linearity of the inverse Laplace transform to find: $$L^{-1}(Θ(s))(t)=2^{n+1}n!*\frac{t^n}{n!}=2^{n+1}t^{n}$$
I don't know if this is the correct method in some way I feel like it's to simple please advise! Thanks for your time!

Performing the $u=st$ change of variable in the following integral yields
$$\int_0^{+\infty} t^n e^{-st}dt=\frac 1 {s^{n+1}}\int_0^{+\infty}u^ne^{-u}du$$
and using integration by parts, or using the properties of the Gamma function, the integral in the right-hand side is equal to n!, thus
$$\int_0^{+\infty} t^n e^{-st}dt=\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$$
Thus you can conclude that
$L^{-1}(\Theta(s))=2^{n+1}t^n$
